# local website fetch all items from database but in server only fetch one item

Tags: database

We are contacting you today to solve our small issue we have with our website

For your mor information we made this website base on PHP and  in our localhost ( our local computer) is working properly, but when we upload it to the hosting to be online the connection between content and database is limited even the user: ........ in our database: ........ has full privileges.
In our localhost connection has been made and read all the items in the specific category, but when it will go online only shows 1 item even without filtering by any category.

Thank you and best regards

Checked privileged user in the database.